# xpath statement from this xml

Tags: xml, xpath

Not well versed in XPATH....Out of this XML file, I just want to retrieve the company profile information...basically want to get this out:
How do I do this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 <strong>Apple Inc.</strong>
                                    <br/>
                                    <p>1 Infinite Loop
                    <br/>Cupertino, CA 95014
                    <br/>United States -
```

XML is entered here [`http://pythonfiddle.com/xml-xpath-query`](http://pythonfiddle.com/xml-xpath-query)

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Please: a) Include XPath expressions that you have already tried. b) Avoid referring to a URL outside StackOverflow since the URL may become obsolete rendering the question and solution uncomprehensible. c) Define exactly what you want extract. Looking at the URL that you provided and the excerpt given above it is difficult to say what made you stop after the hyphen. It looks slightly arbitrary.

Comment: P.S. How does this question of yours relate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105855? Aren't you asking the same thing?

Comment: @MarcusRickert a) I have tried 
`SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=AAPL+Profile" and xpath="'//class[@id="yfnc_modtitlew1"]"`

Comment: @MarcusRickert b)I apologize about that. However, the XML was so long, that stackoverflow was not allowing it to post the question. c)I want to extract the address information, as listed above. After United States, there's a dash, and then the url to the map, I don't really care about that part. The other question is deleted. Sorry about that. Thanks in advance for any information you can provide me. This is not my strong point.

Comment: If the XML is too long to post, then it is too long for SO volunteers to study. You need to distill its essence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very specific to this data only.

To get the title in your data, e.g. The Apple Inc portion, Use the following xPath

```
//td[@class="yfnc_modtitlew1"]/strong[1]
```

And to get the data in the paragraph (Address details etc), use the following :

```
//td[@class="yfnc_modtitlew1"]/p[1]
```

Now a few more tips. To better learn the xPath syntax, Use a cheatsheet like the following : http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp . And you can test your xpath expressions on something like this : http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: Thanks, this works very well! I am very grateful.